# Create non-root user and disable root SSH in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write an Ansible playbook to bootstrap my servers. By default on Linode I can only login as root with a password, so my playbook logs in as root, creates a non-root user with an SSH key, and disables root and password SSH.

This is a problem because I now can't run that playbook again since root login is disabled! I would like the playbook to be idempotent and not have to add and remove hosts after bootstrapping them.

Comment: You may find some inspiration [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698067/ansible-check-if-my-user-exists-on-remote-host-else-use-root-user-to-connect-w/39699075#39699075).

Answer (score 12):

I like to do it this way:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Check ansible user
      command: ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 ansible@{{ inventory_hostname }} "echo OK"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      changed_when: false
      failed_when: false
      register: check_ansible_user
    - block:
      - name: Create Ansible user
        user:
          name: ansible
          comment: "Ansible user"
          password: $6$u3GdHI6FzXL01U9q$LENkJYHcA/NbnXAoJ1jzj.n3a7X6W35rj2TU1kSx4cDtgOEV9S6UboZ4BQ414UDjVvpaQhTt8sXVtkPvOuNt.0
          shell: /bin/bash
      - name: Add authorized key
        authorized_key:
          user: ansible
          key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
          exclusive: yes
      - name: Allow sudo for ansible
        copy:
          content: ansible ALL=(ALL) ALL
          dest: /etc/sudoers.d/ansible
          mode: 0600
      when: check_ansible_user | failed
```

I try to connect to the remote host with my ansible user. If this is impossible (on the first run), I connect as root and create the ansible user along with its `authorized_keys` file and `sudo` rights.

On subsequent runs, connecting as ansible user works, so the block of tasks can be skipped.

Once the remote host is bootstrapped, I can go on with the ansible user and `become`:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: ansible
  become: yes
  roles:
    - ...
```

Comment: Are you manually changing the `remote_user` in your playbook after that first run? That isn't idempotent. I hope I'm missing something.

Comment: You do, I don't change anything manually. The two codesamples represent two different plays (maybe it helps to imagine them as being called `bootstrap.yml` and `site.yml`, where `site.yml` includes `bootstrap.yml` before anything else). If the first task of `bootstrap.yml` fails, *all other tasks* of this play are skipped and `site.yml` takes over.

Comment: copy-pasted the code snippet, but ansible skips that block of tasks: `"skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"`. Running the play with `-vvv` shows the ssh call returns `"msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 255,`

Comment: I fixed changing the `when` condition: `when: not "OK" in check_ansible_user.stdout`

Answer (score 3):

If you create your servers on Linode with the [linode module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/linode_module.html) you could register the `return value` of the `linode` task and include the the bootstrap tasks with an condition checking the outout of the linode task. That should be idempotent. Try something like this:

```
- linode:
    api_key: 'longStringFromLinodeApi'
    name: linode-test1
    plan: 1
    datacenter: 2
    distribution: 99
    password: 'superSecureRootPassword'
    private_ip: yes
    ssh_pub_key: 'ssh-rsa qwerty'
    swap: 768
    wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 600
    state: present
  register: linode_node

- include: bootstrap.yml
  when: linode_node.changed
```

`bootstrap.yml` would than contain all the tasks necessary to disable ssh root login and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

- create a role (something like 'base') where you (amongst other things), create a suitable user (and sudo rules) for ansible to use
- create or adapt your role for SSH, to manage `sshd_config` (I would tend to recommend you manage the entire file, using a `template`, but that is up to you), and disable root logins
- make your SSH role depend on the base role, e.g. using meta.

For the first role (the base one), I tend to use something like:

```
 name: base | local ansible user | create user
  user:
    name: "{{ local_ansible_user }}"
    group: "{{ local_ansible_group }}"
    home: "/home/{{ local_ansible_user }}"
    state: present
    generate_ssh_key: "{{ local_ansible_generate_key }}"
    ssh_key_bits: 4096
    ssh_key_type: rsa
  tags:
    - ansible
    - local_user

- name: base | local ansible user | provision authorised keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ local_ansible_user }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ local_ansible_authorised_keys }}"
  tags:
    - ansible
    - authorised_keys
```

For the SSH config, I would use:

```
- name: openssh | server | create configuration
  template:
    src: sshd_config.j2
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "0640"
    validate: "/usr/sbin/sshd -tf %s"
  notify:
    - openssh | server | restart
  tags:
    - ssh
    - openssh
```

Ansible's role dependencies are documented [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies).

You could also just use ordering within your playbook to do this.

I have some [ansible stuff on github](https://github.com/iwaseatenbyagrue/ansible) (from which the above is taken), if you want to see it in context

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could just modify the `ansible_ssh_user` in the [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) after you have bootstrapped the host?

```
[targets]

other1.example.com ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=root # new host
other2.example.com ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=user # bootstrapped host
```